# How to group records and aggregate total

Tags: sql, sql-server

All,

I have the following records in a table. Basing on `timesheetID,jobId,Startime` I need to aggregate time spend on a each job everyday. Can some one suggest best way?

```
jobID     startTime                 endTime              totalTime             timesheetID
4         2012-09-10                 2012-09-10            1.466667              12300
4         2012-09-10                 2012-09-10            1.466667              12300
4         2012-09-11                 2012-09-11            5.116667              12300
12        2012-09-10                 2012-09-10            1.466667              12300
12        2012-09-11                 2012-09-11                0.3               12300
4         2012-09-10                 2012-09-10            1.433333              12400
12        2012-09-11                 2012-09-11            4.966667              12400
13        2012-09-10                 2012-09-10                 2.2              12400
12        2012-09-11                 2012-09-11            0.3333333             12400
4         2012-09-11                 2012-09-11             0.4833333            12400
4         2012-09-10                 2012-09-10               2.016667           12600
13        2012-09-11                 2012-09-11               4.866667           12600
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: this is the most basic of SUM aggregate functions.  post what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the aggregate function `SUM()` and a `GROUP BY`:

```
select timesheetid, jobid, starttime, sum(totaltime) TotTime
from yourtable
group by timesheetid, jobid, starttime
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4135/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregate `SUM` and `GROUP BY`. Try this code on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77ea8/2)